# is it possible drupal 8 about us page more dynamic like this and want change twig template for each page diff-rents?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-theming

i am  new drupal guys i have not knowledge about drupal when started one month before much learn from drupal 8
  my problem is how can change  page title file (field-node-title-html.twig)different each page.also want change content body here snapshot attached [SCREENSHOT](http://unitedbank.mvcdev.com/ub/Screenshot.pdf)
    this is my about us page how to show like this? advance "thanks" comment on every response glad for me

Comment: i dont know this quetion is properway to ask community.not then suggest me b'coz i am new drupal delvloper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the page title file, you can either update/create the file page.html.twig and change it in their, or adding a module which will give you the ability to do it, like [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) to do like.

Concerning your screenshot, the quality is really bad so it's hard to help you. But it seems that there is a big block of HTML on the top (region header?), then 2 views-block to create inside a panel, then a block of HTML in the bottom (region footer?).

If you don't know how to organize your page, you might ask for some Drupal training, to help you with the basics.

I hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: thanks.giving me kind of information i have attach pdf for more clear